# How to Fix Jsoup nullpointerexception in android studio 2019

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jsoup

I am creating an app in which i want to scrape google data with the help of jsoup and show it to text view in android studio.

But after doing some coding with the help of jsoup i am getting following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.yasht.cricketapp, PID: 11929
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String org.jsoup.nodes.Element.text()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.yasht.cricketapp.Bottomnav.score_scrape.doInBackground(score_scrape.java:30)
    at com.example.yasht.cricketapp.Bottomnav.score_scrape.doInBackground(score_scrape.java:13)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

this is my jsoup code with async task :

```
    public class score_scrape extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

 String words;
 TextView score;

public score_scrape( TextView score){
    this.score =score;

}


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=india+vs+australia+3rd+odi+live+score").get();
            Element element = doc.select("div[imspo_mh_cricket__score-major]").first();
            words = element.text();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        score.setText(words);
    }
}
```

I am using async task method which is declared i my main activity.

Comment for any further information.

Comment: Your `element ` return null and your `doc.select` wrong you are not following hierarchy.

Comment: @manfromnowhere what is correct hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

In your case you don't want to use `select` You can simply change below line.

Change  line  from

`Element element = doc.select("div[imspo_mh_cricket__score-major]").first();`

To

`Element element = doc.getElementsByClass("imspo_mh_cricket__score-major").first();`

Output:

```
230
```

Comment: thanks it's working